# Teste de conexão com o PHPMailer

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, email, phpmailer, cms

Trabalho com o PHPMailer a um tempo, agora estou o inserindo em um Gerenciador de Conteúdo mais complexo e pelo painel a pessoa poderá inserir vários e-mails para ser o Remetente do PHPMailer em diversas situações (por exemplo: email de contato, recuperação de senha, confirmação de cadastro...), então no gerenciador a pessoa poderá modificar os dados de acesso do email (host, email, senha e porta) e salvar, mas ao salvar queria fazer uma validação e só aceitar emails com os dados que estejam funcionando!

Precisava de um método de fazer um teste de configuração!

Alguém conhece esse método dentro do PHPMailer, que ele apenas faça um teste de conexão, mas não envie nenhum e-mail no ato de teste.

O código que estou tentando usar é esse:

```
    // Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
    require_once("phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    require_once("phpmailer/class.smtp.php");

    $host = "mx1.weblink.com.br";
    $porta = 587;
    $email = "teste@gabrielprogramador.com.br";
    $senha = "teste123";

    $smtp = new SMTP;

    if ( !$smtp->connect($host, $porta) ) {
        // erro ao conectar
        echo 'Erro ao conectar o SMTP';
    }

    if ( !$smtp->startTLS() ) {
        // erro ao iniciar TLS
        echo 'Erro ao iniciar o TLS';
    }

    if ( !$smtp->authenticate($email, $senha) ) {
        // erro ao autenticar o usuário
        echo 'Erro ao autenticar o usuário de e-mail e senha';
    }
```

O host, e os dados de acessos são reais, criei para fazer esses testes mesmo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a classe [SMTP](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/SMTP.html) do PHPMailer para verificar a conexão:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$smtp = new SMTP;

if ( !$smtp->connect( 'host', 'porta' ) ) {
    // erro ao conectar
}

if ( !$smtp->startTLS() ) {
    // erro ao iniciar TLS
}

// Necessário enviar o comando EHLO após iniciar o TLS,
// caso contrário não será possível autenticar.
if ( !$smtp->hello(gethostname()) ) {
    // erro ao enviar o comando EHLO
}

if ( !$smtp->authenticate( 'usuario', 'senha' ) ) {
    // erro ao autenticar o usuário
}
```

fonte: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp_check.phps

Comment: Vou testar isso então, obrigado!

Comment: Marcos, ele valida o tls e o connect, mas sempre que chega no authenticate() sempre da erro. Se eu uso os mesmos dados no envio normal ele envia o e-mail.

Comment: @GabrielGarcia pode atualizar a sua pergunta com o código que está usando para testar a conexão?

Comment: Fiz a edição na pergunta!

Comment: @GabrielGarcia testei local e se não enviar o comando EHLO não da pra autenticar. Atualizei minha resposta com o código para enviar o comando EHLO após iniciar o TLS.    
    
PS: não esqueça de remover esse usuário de teste

Comment: Resolveu meus problemas Marcos, show!
Muito obrigado!

Comment: @GabrielGarcia disponha :)